# Set Identity_insert on - Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, merge-replication

I have merge replication set up between two databases and am using identity ranges on both.

I want to add a specific row to a merged table (setting the identity value to something outside of the identity range) on the publisher.  When I try this, I get the following error.

> The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check
>   constraint in database 'xxx', replicated table 'dbo.yyy', column
>   'yyy_id'. If the identity column is automatically managed by
>   replication, update the range as follows: for the Publisher, execute
>   sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange; for the Subscriber, run the
>   Distribution Agent or the Merge Agent.

Is there a way to force specific identity value into a merge replicated table that is using identity range management?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to ensure that each node in the replication topology is using a different range of identity values, so that duplicates do not occur.

> For example, the Publisher could be
>   assigned the range 1-100, Subscriber A
>   the range 101-200, and Subscriber B
>   the range 201-300. If a row is
>   inserted at the Publisher and the
>   identity value is, for example, 65,
>   that value is replicated to each
>   Subscriber. When replication inserts
>   data at each Subscriber, it does not
>   increment the identity column value in
>   the Subscriber table; instead, the
>   literal value 65 is inserted. Only
>   user inserts, but not replication
>   agent inserts cause the identity
>   column value to be incremented.

Ref. [Replicating Identity Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152543(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mitch, but in the situation I am dealing with, customers are actively entering records in both the pub and sub which are getting assigned Ids.  There is a specific ID I want to insert into the pub (lower than current Range).  but I want custs who are adding to the pub to add within the range.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by increasing Automatic insert by increasing 20000 row . 
[Helpful blog added here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6093/sql-server-merge-replication-identity-range-management/)